# aws workspace: How to control access to s3 folders inside a bucket to particular user in aws workspace

Tags: amazon-workspaces

I am creating aws workspaces for set of customers. Each customer we want to provide them with a folder in a s3 bucket.

The contents of this s3 folder will only be for read only access.

How can I do this

example:

```
SomeS3bucket (bucket)
--- customer1 (folder)
--- customer2 (folder)
...
```

now only customer1 (folder) will be accessible for the customer1 user in aws workspace.